# How to overload/override admin directory in child theme?

Tags: wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming, admin

I am using minamaze theme i have created it's child theme to do some modification i need to change in admin>main>options>homepage.php file. so how should i overload/override in my child theme?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your specific theme, but to override any page template in a child theme, you simply need to put the same file in your child theme folder (in your example, homepage.php).  Then, the changes to your homepage.php should overwrite the parent theme file.  More info about child themes:  http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes  (look under the "template files" header)

Comment: tnx for reply... I'm aware of this solution that you have mentioned, even i have override header, footer and style.css files, but problem remains same for homepage.php. Hope you have slolution